# Mockito, Usages of doNothing() When()

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to Mockito, and I went over this example but there is one step that I do not understand when it calls `doNothing()` on the first line of the method:

```
@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void testConsecutiveCalls() throws Exception(){
  doNothing().doThrow(Exception.class).when(b).voidMethod();
  a.usesVoidMethod()
  verify(b).voidMethod();
  a.usesVoidMethod()
}
```

I do understand that when the first time `voidMehtod()` is called is returning nothing and in the second time it is giving an exception.

But if we remove the `doNothing.doThrow(Exception.class).when(b).voidMethod();`, won't the test still be valid and will test what we want to test that the method throw an exception in the second time?

Answer (score 5):

A few points, numbered just for ease of reference:

1. The default behavior of a *mock* is to return an appropriate dummy value every time, often zero, `null`, or an empty string. The default behavior of a spy is to call the spy's real implementation. Of course, through parameters to `@Mock` or `Mockito.mock`, you can use an arbitrary Answer or any of Mockito's [standard](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Answers.html) or [additional](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html) answers.
2. When multiple actions are given as a part of a chain, Mockito will do each action in sequence and forever repeat the final action.

   ```
   // calls to foo.bar() return 1, 2, 3, 3, 3...
   doReturn(1).thenReturn(2, 3).when(foo).bar();
   ```

   Note that this is within the same chain; the most-recently-defined matching chain wins, so separate statements wouldn't have the same effect.

   ```
   doReturn(1).thenReturn(2).when(foo).baz();
   doReturn(3).thenReturn(4).when(foo).baz();
   // calls return 3, 4, 4, 4... because the first chain is entirely overridden.
   ```
3. `doNothing`, then, gets most of its value from either *overriding default behavior* or *setting up an action in a chain*.

So what the test is *trying* to do is to `doNothing` the first time such that the verification will succeed, and then `doThrow` the second time to satisfy the expected exception. Though a failed `verify` would (correctly) fail the test because [Mockito's errors subclass Error and not Exception](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/exceptions/base/MockitoAssertionError.html), you're right that a removal of the `doNothing` would still cause the test to pass by throwing the exception on the first call to `a.usesVoidMethod()`. Though this is fine enough for the test--after all, you can see the `doNothing` in the test itself--a more robust test might look like this:

```
@Test
public void testConsecutiveCalls() throws Exception(){
  doNothing().doThrow(SomeKnownException.class).when(b).voidMethod();
  a.usesVoidMethod();
  verify(b).voidMethod();
  try {
    a.usesVoidMethod();
    fail();
  } catch (SomeKnownException expected) { /* OK */ }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `doNothing` method doesn't change the behaviour of a `mocked' method, but the declaration of the`doThrow`does. If you have a spy and don't want a method to be executed, then`doNothing` will change the behaviour.

Comment: so how does `doThrow(Exception.class)` is changing it?
If I do remove `doNothing().doThrow(Exception.class).when(b).voidMethod();` what is the side effect behind doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This test is a poor test because (a) it doesn't make much sense, (b) it's testing two different things:

1. `a.usesVoidMethod()` calls `b.voidMethod()`.
2. When the dependency `b` throws a `Exception`, the object under test `a` throws a `RuntimeException`.

and (c), it's named incorrectly.  It's testing the two things above independently, and the fact that they're consecutive calls is irrelevant.

If you remove the first line of this test method, then you remove the behavior of `b` that is being mocked.  The test will then fail since a void method call on a mock will do nothing by default; i.e., there will be no `Exception` from `b`, and thus no `RuntimeException` from `a`.

You are correct that if `a` was actually coded so that it threw a `RuntimeException` if it was called twice, then the mocking of `b` would not be needed.  But that would be even less reasonable than it is already.